# Making a series of plots that proceed by a click

Tags: r

In the example below I would like to be able to control when I go to the next plot by a using mouse click (or keyboard entry)

```
for (i in 1:5){
    plot(1:i)
    Sys.sleep(1)
    #add something here that requests mouse click to proceed
}
```

Is this possible? There is a setting in the X11() help file caled 'clickToConfirm' but I can't work out what that does.

It would also be helpful to me to be to be able to scroll back and forth through plots using the arrow keys. Is this possible?

Currently if I need to look at lots of plots I output them into a big .pdf file and scroll though them all there, but that is a bit cumbersome.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In R, that would be done by setting `par(ask=TRUE)`. Try the following code, which shows how to reset the par when exiting the function :

```
op <- par(ask=TRUE)
for (i in 1:5){
    plot(1:i)
}
par(op)
```

If you want to keep a history to browse through, you can either open a window and click on `recording` in the `History`  menu, or you can open the window yourself with the history on. Demonstrated in a function :

```
plot.fun <- function(){
    windows(record=TRUE) # opens a window and starts recording
    op <- par(ask=TRUE)
    on.exit(par(op))

    for (i in 1:5){
        plot(1:i)
    }
    windows.options(record=FALSE) #stops recording.
}
plot.fun()
```

This will however keep all previous plots in the history for browsing as well, so if you run this code 3 times you'll have 15 plots in the plot history. Also note that the open plot window will keep on recording until you turn off the recording in the menu.

You can play with the plot history, as you'll have a variable `.SavedPlots` which contains the saved plot history. It can be cleared using the menu `History > clear history` in the plot window. If you want to clear the history from the console, you could hack that by

```
.SavedPlots <- NULL
```

But I advise you not to do this, as changing the `.SavedPlots` variable can cause R to crash.

See also `?windows` and ?recordPlot for a bit more information. But as you're getting close to the internal code of R, be warned that you can get pretty awkward behaviour if you start playing around with these things.

Comment: Thats great, thanks. But do you know the answer to the second part of my question - 'can you scroll back and forth through plots using (say) the arrow keys?

Answer (score 7):

For scrolling back and forth between plots using the arrow keys: it depends on the platform/R interface.

- Windows: there is a recording function (see Q5 of the [R for Windows FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html)) which uses Page Up/Page Down
- MacOS: under the standard GUI, the Quartz window has Apple-left and Apple-right arrow
- under the standard Unix (no-GUI) interface, things are more limited.  You can use [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org/) (which has a lot of buzz right now) ... I would have thought that [JGR](http://rforge.net/JGR/index.html) would have plot history as well, but it doesn't seem to ...

Comment: +1 for mentioning RStudio and the different options on different OS

Answer (score 5):

You can use locator - now plots change on click

```
for (i in 1:5){
    plot(1:i)
    locator(1)
}
```

Comment: plots change on two clicks to be exact.